# Difference between an Object and its Prototype

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

Why does:

```
console.log(Object.hasOwnProperty("hasOwnProperty"));
```

return a false, But:

```
console.log(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty("hasOwnProperty"));
```

return a true statement?

I realize that hasOwnProperty is a pre-built method in the Object but I guess my question is what is the difference between the Object and the prototype of an Object.
Aren't they one and the same?
When we refer to the Object in the first line of code, aren't we referring to the same line of code in the second line of code above?

**EDIT: fixed above 2 lines of code from:**

```
console.log(Object.hasOwnProperty);
```

**and:**

```
console.log(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty);
```

Comment: Since `hasOwnProperty` is a function, I don't see how you can be getting `true` or `false` on the console... can you provide some complete code that demonstrates what you're seeing?

Comment: Umm, neither of them should log a Boolean, but the same function?

Comment: FWIW: `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty === Object.hasOwnProperty` is `true`

Comment: I aplogize my code should have read:  
console.log(Object.hasOwnProperty("hasOwnProperty"));
console.log(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty("hasOwnProperty"));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `Object.hasOwnProperty` and `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty` reference the *same* function. `Object.prototype` contains that function as an *own* property, while `Object` contains it as an *inherited* property.

So, in other words, the `hasOwnProperty` function is defined (as a method) on the `Object.prototype` object. Then, the `Object` constructor (like almost all other native objects) inherits (all methods) from `Object.prototype`.

Btw, the inheritance chain (prototype chain) of `Object` is:

```
Object -> Function.prototype -> Object.prototype -> null
```

So, `Object` inherits all methods from both `Function.prototype`, and `Object.prototype`.

Comment: So whenever we create a new object, do we essentially create a prototype and an instance of that prototype? 
For example if we create a new object:

    var newObject = new someObject();  

Have we in essence created a someObject.prototype object and another object newObject that inherits from someObject at the same time?

Comment: @Moolla Nope. `var foo = new Foo();` creates only one object - the `foo` instance object. The `Foo.prototype` object (from which `foo` inherits) already existed - it was created at the same time the `Foo` constructor function was originally created. So, when you write `function Foo () { ... }`, this creates the `Foo` constructor function *and* the `Foo.prototype` object.

Comment: so to reiterate:  
When I initially create a function constructor **function Foo() {...}** , this essentially creates the actual constructor _and_ a prototype of the constructor (Foo.prototype) as a side-effect.            
The Foo.prototype contains the hasOwnProperty method while the foo object **var foo = new Foo();** does not actually contain the hasOwnProperty, which is why **console.log(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty("hasOwnProperty"));** returns true and **console.log(Object.hasOwnProperty("hasOwnProperty"));** returns false.
_Thanks for sticking with me so far._

Comment: @Moolla Yes, except `Foo.prototype` does *not* contain the `hasOwnProperty` method, `Object.prototype` does. When `function Foo () {}`, `Foo.prototype` is initially an empty object, and you have to assign methods manually. In JavaScript, every function you define (whether you use it as a constructor or not) contains a "prototype" property. The JavaScript language provides it just in case, as there is no way of specifying which functions you intend to use as constructors.

Comment: I think I'm getting it. But when you say that prototype is a property of Foo as in `funtion Foo() { prototype; }` as in that prototype is actually a property of the object constructor with a blank value?

Comment: @Moolla Yes, when I say a property, I mean an actually property of the constructor object :) So, you refer to it like so: `Foo.prototype`. What you wrote does not define a `prototype` property, however, if you had written `function Foo () { var prototype; }`, then that would create a local variable of the constructor. Notice how local variables of the constructor are *not* the same as properties of the constructor.

Comment: I'm sorry for having to suck you in this hell hole that is my never-ending questions but...So this is the deal (as I understand it): If I create an object constructor:`function Foo(){};` and then an object: `var foo = new Foo();`, does the constructor and the object automatically get assigned a `var prototype;` property? And then is it these properties that contain the inherited **hasOwnProperty** method that is actually contained in the **Object.prototype**? And is this **Object** that **Object.prototype** belongs to simply there as a characteristic of Javascript. Sorry if this is too much...

Comment: `function Foo () {}` creates a constructor function with an accompanying `Foo.prototype` object (initially an empty object). This `Foo.prototype` inherits from `Object.prototype`. Now, `var foo = new Foo();` creates an instance of `Foo`. This instance inherits from `Foo.prototype`. So, `foo` inherits `hasOwnProperty`. The inheritance chain of `foo` is: `foo -> Foo.prototype -> Object.prototype -> null`, so `foo` inherits from *both* `Foo.prototype`, *and* `Object.prototype`. *** `Object` is a built-in constructor, it's defined by the specification.

Answer (score 0):

> I realize that hasOwnProperty is a pre-built method in the Object.

Actually its a function on a non-enumerable property of the object from which *all* JavaScript objects inherit. This includes the `Object` function object.

> but I guess my question is what is the difference between the Object and the prototype of an Object. Aren't they one and the same?

No, they're definitely not. The [section on Objects](http://es5.github.com/#x4.2.1) in the *Language Overview* of the EcmaScript specification describes it pretty well I think. Each object has a hidden *[[prototype]]* link to the object it inherits from (until `null`) - building the "prototype chain" in which properties are looked up. The public `prototype` property of functions is different from that - it points to the object from which all instances that are constructed by the function will inherit.